# Navigating history/time travel in react-redux using connected-react-router

Tags: react-redux, connected-react-router

I would greatly appreciate any assistance or examples in how to implement time travel on a single-page react-redux app using connected-react-router.

I just want to be able to program links to go back to step1 or step2 once I'm on step3 or step4 and have the correct state information for that step (not current state).

I get that I should store my data in the state on history/location. But I don't know how to program links to navigate back to step1 or step2.

Any examples for doing this would be helpful. Thanks so much!

Comment: Did you try the example from documentation? Did you have any issues with it?
https://redux.js.org/advanced/usagewithreactrouter

Comment: Thanks for your help! I did not see that particular documentation but now that I have reviewed it, it doesn't quite answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will help it **createMemoryHistory**: [history npm pakacge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/history).

So you can get the previous value route. 
Example:

```
const prevRoute = history.entries[history.index - 1].pathname;
```